# How to save Excel workbook to current user desktop by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, activex

I create workbook from web page by:

```
var thisTable = document.getElementById("mytable3").innerHTML;
       window.clipboardData.setData("Text", thisTable);
       var objExcel = new ActiveXObject ("Excel.Application");
       objExcel.visible = true;
       var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add();
       var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1);
       objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate;
       objWorksheet.name = "test";
       objWorksheet.Paste;
       objWorksheet.columns.autofit;
       window.clipboardData.setData("Text","");
       objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).SaveAs("%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\xxx.xls");
```

But for `objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).SaveAs("%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\xxx.xls");` — it doesn't save to desktop and gives this error:

```
SCRIPT1004: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\B612F000'. There are several possible reasons:
• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.
```

Answer (score 1):

You assume that javascript expands environment variables inside an string. Unfortunately for you, it does not.

you'll need to expand it in your code. Use the Environment property of the wscript.shell object to access any environment variable.

first, access the wscript.shell object. In WSH, use

```
var wshell = WScript.CreateObject("wscript.shell");
```

or in the browser use

```
var wshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
```

and then

```
var userProfile = wshell.Environment("USERPROFILE");
```

or you can expand the variable inside your string by using ExpandEnvironmentStrings method

```
objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).SaveAs(
  wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\xxx.xls")
);
```

Comment: `var wshell = WScript.CreateObject("wscript.shell");`
Give this error SCRIPT5009: 'WScript' is undefined

Comment: this is available in Windows Script Hosting. In browsers use ActiveXObject. I have edited the answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

From @PA. Answer 
I finally got an answer by

```
//For Expand environment
  var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  var userProfile = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\test.xls");

  //For Save
  objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).SaveAs(userProfile);
```

Thak You @PA.